# Jekyll liquid template with variable parameter

Tags: variables, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I want to build something like this:

```
{% my_liquid_template "some parameter" %}
```

However I want it to **also accept this**:

```
{% my_liquid_template "{{ site.url }}/feed.rss" %}
```

The first one is easy. The second one just does not parse `{{ site.url }}`. How can I do that?

This is not about writing a liquid template plugin. I now how to do that. However I would like to **pass the liquid template `"{{ site.url }}/feed.rss"` as a parameter**.

I do not want to append the `site.url` in the liquid template code, because this will break `{% my_liquid_template "some parameter" %}`.

Even this does not work

```
{% my_liquid_template site.url %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest tags in Liquid markup.

You could assign the variable then use it further down, for example:

```
{% assign my_site = site.url %}
{{ my_liquid_template my_site}}
```